# api request does not work in react-native

Tags: android, node.js, reactjs, react-native, android-studio

i'm using react-native

When I run the emulator virtually the api is well requested to the backend router.

However, when I actually test it on my Android device, the api request does not reach the backend.

My front port number is 8081 and my back end is 3065.

this is my code

for example my ip address: 49.174.243.53

(front.js)

```
    const Kakao = ({navigation}) => {
      const hello = async () => {
        const {data} = await axios.post('http://43.164.243.53:3065/kakao/test', {
          hi: 'hi2',
        });
      };
      return (
        <LoginButton style={{marginTop: 30}} onPress={hello}>
          <Label>hello</Label>
        </LoginButton>
      );
    };

    export default Kakao;
```

(back/app.js)

```
    const express = require('express');
    const dotenv = require('dotenv');
    const morgan = require('morgan');
    const path = require('path');
    const kakaoRouter = require('./routes/kakao');
    const db = require('./models');

    dotenv.config();
    const app = express();
    db.sequelize
      .sync()
      .then(() => {
        console.log('db 연결 성공');
      })
      .catch(console.error);
    passportConfig();

    app.use(morgan('dev'));
    app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'uploads')));
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));

    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
      res.send('hello express');
    });

    app.use('/kakao', kakaoRouter);

    app.listen(3065, () => {
      console.log('서버 실행 중!');
    });
```

(back/router)

```
    router.post('/test', async (req, res, next) => {
      //whic is  kakao/test
      try {
        console.log('req.body:::::::::', req.body);
        return res.status(200).json({
          posts: 'h!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!',
        });
      } catch (error) {
        next(error); // status 500
      }
    });
```

Comment: try enabling CORS or use localhost instead of IP

Comment: @folan i tired but it doesn't work...

Comment: This is pretty much always network configuration.  The server is on your PC?  Make sure your network firewall allows incoming connections to that IP and port.  And make sure you're on wifi not cellular (unless you want to make that IP open to the world).  It works on the emulator because there's a private network between the emulator and host to enable any networking at all.

Answer (score 1):

In order to view remote documents from an HTTP URL, cleartext network traffic support is required. On Android 9.0 (API level 28) or higher, cleartext support is disabled by default and apps targeting Android 9.0 or higher will need to add the **android:usesClearTextTraffic="true**" flag in the **AndroidManifest.xml** file.

> If you are only working with HTTPS files, this flag is not required